# How to convert a string to an array in FreeMarker

Tags: arrays, list, freemarker

I have got stuck in one problem:

If the user give the value of `a = abhay, himanshu, aman, piyush`
they have not mentioned like this `a = ["abhay","himanshu","aman","piyush"]`.

So how should I use this `a` as an array in this:

```
<#list a as x>
${x}
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string builtin `?split` to split a string by a regular expression:

```
<#list "abhay, himanshu, aman, piyush"?split(", ?", "r") as x>
${x}
</#list>
```

See also:

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_split

Comment: You did not respond to this question, but did ask a new question. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)